# Android ObjectAnimatorSet XML Convert To JAVA Code

Tags: android, xml, objectanimator, animator

these is my animator set in xml, i want convert to java code, but i don't know how to set the "AnimatorSet" in the "AnimatorSet"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="sequentially">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="50"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueFrom="1.0"
            android:valueTo="0.8" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="50"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueFrom="1.0"
            android:valueTo="0.8" />
    </set>

    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="50"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueFrom="0.8"
            android:valueTo="1.1" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="50"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueFrom="0.8"
            android:valueTo="1.1" />
    </set>
</set>
```

Comment: `AnimatorSet` plays multiple `Animator`s, and `AnimatorSet` is `Animator` too as it extends `Animator`, so you can play multiple `AnimatorSet`s

Comment: ha, i see, thank you very much

Comment: but honestly you can do it in one `ObjectAnimator#ofFloat` method call

Comment: mm, i used this, "ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1f, 0.8f, 1.1f, 1f);"

Comment: almost, it scales only on x axis, you need x & y

Comment: ok, it's work well, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create an AnimatorSet to play animation together, and then add two ObjectAnimator to AnimatorSet, like this :

```
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.playTogether(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1, 0.8f, 1.1f),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1, 0.8f, 1.1f)
    );
animatorSet.setDuration(1000);
animatorSet.start();
```